# AWS describe_containers returns empty when queried directly

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ecs

I am using the boto3 sdk to query the AWS ECS API, to fully describe a Fargate cluster.

I first get the services for the cluster, then the tasks for each service.

A task contains a key `containers`, which contains a list of containers. These each have an ARN of the form: `arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-2:822276179620:container/16328278-00a3-334f-b60c-5e966badd794`

I then try to pass these ARNs to boto3's `describe_container_instances`, passing the correct cluster name, and a list of the containerARNs mentioned above. It errors, claiming that the containerIdentiifers are invalid. Through some experimentation, I discovered that if I split off the part of the ARN after `container/` and use that, it no longer errors, but, it claims that all of the containerInstances are 'MISSING' (under the 'failures' key).

Interestingly, if I try to run `list_container_instances` directly on the cluster, it returns an empty list (200 response, no error).

In summary, the API seems unwilling to let me see container directly. I can only see them as members of the task object (which does not contain all of the information about them that I require).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[describe_container_instances](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.describe_container_instances) returns information about **container instances**:

> Describes Amazon Elastic Container Service **container instances**. Returns metadata about registered and remaining resources on each container instance requested.

However, you are running **Fargate** cluster, thus you have no access to the instances. They are managed by AWS.

You would be able to access container instances if you were running [EC2-type cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_types.html#launch-type-ec2), rather than Fargate:

> EC2 Launch Type: The EC2 launch type allows you to run your containerized applications on a cluster of Amazon EC2 **instances** that you manage.

Comment: Ah, understood.  So, is there any way of getting more information about the containers mentioned in the 'containers' key of the task returned by `describe_task`?

Comment: @alex_halford Hi. I don't think so. By using Fargate you get to easy run your tasks, but you loose the ability for more fine grain control and access, as you have with EC2-type clusters. If you want to get detailed information about instances that run your tasks, or fine tune them, you should consider using EC2-type cluster, not Fargate.